# SQL(MYSQL) Select column names where sum of that column > 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble constructing a query, and need help.  Consider the following MYSQL tables.

user table

```
username
tuser
tman
tester
```

usergrouplink table

```
username|groupname
tuser   |grp1
tuser   |grp2
```

group table

```
groupname|reporter|provisioner|manager
grp1     |0       |0          |1
grp2     |0       |1          |1
grp3     |1       |0          |0
```

The group table links a group name (grp1) to a role (reporter, provisioner, manager) based on bit flags (0 or 1)

I need a query that can return a list of role names given a username.  For example, given user 'tuser' is in grp1 and grp2, return a role list of provisioner and manager

```
Role
provisioner
manager
```

I have tried the following, and it seems to work, but I must find a way to simplify it:

```
select distinct Role, 'Roles' from
(
    select 'Reporter' as Role from
    (
        select * from Groups g where g.name in 
        (
            select groupname from UserGroupLink l where l.username='tuser'
        )
    ) x
    where x.reporter>0

    union

    select 'Provisioner' as Role from
    (
        select * from Groups g where g.name in 
        (
            select groupname from UserGroupLink l where l.username='tuser'
        )
    ) x
    where x.provisioner>0

    union

    select 'Manager' as Role from
    (
        select * from Groups g where g.name in 
        (
            select groupname from UserGroupLink l where l.username='tuser'
        )
    ) x
    where x.manager>0
) z
```

The above query works, but it compares against the username 'tuser' three times, once for each role.  I need to modify the query, if possible, to only have the username string literal in a single place (for Java JAAS security if anyone is curious). Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Why do you even have `reporter`, `provisioner` and `manager` columns? You don't even need them, your permissions are bitwise and you could have stored everything in a 3 bit integer. You could have done all of this using 1 tinyint column where you store a decimal representation of a 3 bit integer. Then your query turns into something incredibly trivial such as `WHERE permissions > 0`

Comment: Agreed. That was going to be the original approach, but other team members thought it was not readable enough by non-technical people.

Comment: Non technical people have no business dealing with databases. That's why we create user interfaces that bring our mumbo jumbo hieroglyphs to something they can understand and use. It seems that you're the only capable among your team members, algorithmic decisions and data model should never be determined based on what some non technical person can or can't understand, it's stupid by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind putting the roles into a single row, you can do:

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 (case when reporter > 0 then 'Reporter'
                       when Provisioner > 0 then 'Provisioner'
                       when Manager > 0 then 'Manager'
                  end)
                ) as roles
from user u join
     usergrouplink ugl
     on u.tuser = ugl.tuser join
     groups g
     on ugl.groupname = g.groupname
where u.name = 'tuser';
```

If you have control, you should consider normalizing the `groups` table by creating a `GroupRoles` table with one role per group and one row per role.

EDIT:

If you need multiple rows, you can still do that.  It is just easier to put it one one row:

```
select (case when reporter > 0 and n.n = 1 then 'Reporter'
             when Provisioner > 0 and n.n = 2 then 'Provisioner'
             when Manager > 0 and n.n = 3 then 'Manager'
        end) as role
from user u join
     usergrouplink ugl
     on u.tuser = ugl.tuser join
     groups g
     on ugl.groupname = g.groupname cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3
     ) n
where u.name = 'tuser'
having role is not NULL;
```

Note that this makes use of the `having` clause extension in MySQL.  You can use it without a `group by` and use a column alias for the condition.  Otherwise the logic would need a subquery or complicated `where` statement.

Comment: Thanks; good idea, but I need 1 row for each role instead of comma delimited :( It is looking like this may be impossible, and I may have to request a schema as you suggested

Comment: I see you have edited your answer.  This is perfect now, thanks!